# Corebluetooth lose connection

Tags: objective-c, core-bluetooth

I've two problems.

1. What can i do if i `don't find a service` at the `first try`?

Is this function called anyway:

```
 - (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral
            didDiscoverServices:(NSError *)error{
    if(error != nil){
    [connectedDevice discoverServices:nil];
```

Is it more `reliable` to search for a `service with UUID`?

1. If i `lost` the connection is there `any method called`? Do i need to disconnect and reconnect again or only search for service and characteristics again?

Regards

Comment: Explicit "first try", it's not more reliable, it should be faster and "directed to what service you're interested in".`centralManager:didDisconnectPeripheral:error:` should be called.

Comment: did Disconnect Peripheral is never called :(

Comment: CoreBluetooth[WARNING] <CBCharacteristic: 0x15d5d100 UUID = E7ADD780-B042-4876-AAE1-112855353CC1, Value = <2f4f4b0a 312f3043 30314031 392f3432 0a>, Properties = 0x28, Notifying = YES, Broadcasting = NO> is not a valid characteristic for peripheral <CBPeripheral: 0x15d974d0 identifier = BD591469-4B39-EB65-4E8A-5378E3A6992E, Name = "Modul", state = disconnected>

Comment: I tried to shut down the bluetooth on the one device to check if disconnectPeripheral is called. But i think its called if you 'cancelPeripheralConnection:_connectedPeripheral'

Comment: i missed to delegate. :) thanks @Larme